# How does the Opa Slicer work?

Tags: opa

The first bullet point of [opalang.org](http://opalang.org/) says

> Write simultaneously the frontend and backend code, in the same
>   language, within the same module. Even better: the Opa Slicer
>   automates the calls between client and server. No more manually
>   written AJAX calls or value serialization!

How does the slicer work in auto mode, by what metrics/heuristics does it decide whether to compile code to the front end or backend, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question that deserves a complete article and blog post.

Basically, the granularity of slicing is at the function/value level. Some will be available on one side (either client or server), or both sides.

Values are available for both sides whenever possible. Constraints will limit one side, either for platform requirements or security considerations.

The main heuristic is then to stay on a given side whenever possible.